# Listview that shows unread messages in bold and read messages in normal font in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, modem, bold

I have list view that I use to display SMS from my GSM modem. I am reading the port for messages, parsing them and then displaying them. The format that I get when I read messages are:

```
+CMGL: 5,"REC READ","IA-612345","","2012/08/04 11:54:00+22"
Some text message
```

Code that I use to parse:

```
public ShortMessageCollection ParseMessages(string input)
{
    ShortMessageCollection messages = new ShortMessageCollection();
    Regex r = new Regex(@"\+CMGL: (\d+),""(.+)"",""(.+)"",(.*),""(.+)""\r\n(.+)\r\n");
    Match m = r.Match(input);
    while (m.Success)
    {
        ShortMessage msg = new ShortMessage();
        msg.Index = m.Groups[1].Value;
        msg.Status = m.Groups[2].Value;
        msg.Sender = m.Groups[3].Value;
        msg.Alphabet = m.Groups[4].Value;
        msg.Sent = m.Groups[5].Value;
        msg.Message = m.Groups[6].Value;
        messages.Add(msg);
        m = m.NextMatch();
    }
}
return messages;
```

The loop that I use to add messages to list view :

```
foreach (ShortMessage msg in objShortMessageCollection)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { msg.Sender, msg.Message, msg.Sent, msg.Index });
    item.Tag = msg;
    lvwMessages.Items.Insert(0, item);
}
```

Now my requirement is when i add messages to listview, the messages which are unread(REC UNREAD) should be displayed in **bold** font and messages READ should be displayed in normal font. Is this possible? Please let me know the procedure.

Comment: Have you [searched](https://www.google.se/search?q=bold+text+listviewitem) for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (condition)
{
    item.Font = New Font(item.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
}
```

Comment: Great one. I dint know it was so simple. Thnaks :)

Comment: @ flem :Also please help in this- I have listview mouse doubleclick event. On double click, the selected item font should be made normal

Comment: @Cdeez. ListView has a `MouseDoubleClick` event. Subscribe to this and alter the item in the same was as my posted answer `item.Font = New Font(item.Font, FontStyle.Regular);` changing the style to `Regular`.